# Avoiding redundant DB queries in JSF and conditionally rendering a ui:repeat

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF and Hibernate in my application. Say I have a user account, whose questions I want to display using `<ui:repeat>`, in a `<ul>` unordered list. I don't want to render the list if there are no questions, and display "No questions" text instead. The way I currently account is the following:

```
<ul>
<ui:repeat value="#{user.questions}" var="question">
    <li>#{question.text}</li>
</ui:repeat>
</ul>

<h:outputText rendered=#{user.questions.size() == 0}">no questions</h:outputText>
```

There are two problems with this, the stray `<ul>` tags if there are no questions.

Should I encapsulate it in another panel with again `rendered=#{user.questions.size() > 0}` because it seems `ui:repeat` does not accept rendered property.

The second problem is that `user.questions.size()` is calculated twice (and `user.questions` is accessed in two different places), does that mean two hits for the same variable in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I encapsulate it in another panel with again `rendered=#{user.questions.size() > 0}` because it seems `ui:repeat` does not accept rendered property.

Yes.

> The second problem is that `user.questions.size()` is calculated twice (and `user.questions` is accessed in two different places), does that mean two hits for the same variable in db?

Such behaviour should be handled in your model by appropriately scoping and caching the data.

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class DemoBean {

  private List<Question> questions;

  public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    if(questions == null) {
      questions = lookupQuestions();
    }
    return questions;
  }

  // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, I am actually getting the User.Question data through a DAO from Hibernate. Do you know whether Hibernate caches that (is second level cache related), or I should write a wrapper as you suggested?

Comment: @ustun - I would ask a new question detailing how you're using/how you've configured your DAOs and tag it with Hibernate.